# Filter works not excluding results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I have simple js filter that you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/qyy810xx/

So i've stucked with separation of filter's results. I mean that i need to have this:
1) If checked category A, we can see div class="categorya" only;
2) If checked category B, we can see div class="categoryb" only;
3) If checked category A and category B, we can see div class="categorya categoryb" only

I'm not very good at jquery, so this will be fine if you offer any solution.
Thank you!

```js
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

  var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join("|"));
  $("div.bankomat-f").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this[re.source != "" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
  });
});
```

```css
.categorya,
.categoryb,
.categoryrko,
.categoryab,
.categorybb,
.categoryrkob {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.categoryb,
.categorybb {
  background: blue;
}

.categorya.categoryb {
  background: purple;
}

#filters-b {
  display: inline-box;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" />
    <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" />
    <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="categoryrko" id="filter-categoryrko" />
    <label for="filter-categoryrko">RKO</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="bankomat-f categorya categoryb">A, B</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categorya">A</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categorya">A</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categorya">A</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categoryrko">RKO</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categoryb">B</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categoryb">B</div>
<div class="bankomat-f categoryb">B</div>
```

Comment: you are using an `OR` logic not `AND`

Comment: hmm, so how can i change it?

Comment: " Then if you select Category B and deselect it again: the purple box [A,B] will disapear because the script commands to hide 'B'" ; I cant see this in operation; i.e purple box is not disappearing as u have said; so  what is the problem here?

Comment: It's working on the `:checked` elements, so won't hide b but will show b's when checked. @RajkumarSomasundaram

Comment: The problem is with selecting TWO classes. That is when we check and `categorya`, and `categoryb` together, we must see only [A,B] block, not other.